# How To Put Whole Directory struture of local file system in javafx2 tableview cell and traverse that directory

Tags: javafx-2

How To Put Whole Directory struture of local file system in javafx2 tableview cell and traverse that directory?

Please help me friends.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What is your problem? Creating the TableView? Traverse the File System?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Putting a FileSystem into a TableView sounds unreasonable. A TreeView would fit this a lot better.

**Traversing**

For traversing I use the new NIO System (new IO)

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(folderPath)) {
    for (Path child : stream) {

    }                   
} catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```